# colorbox on android doesn't work with 'elastic' transition

Tags: colorbox

On the colorbox examples page:
[www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

the first example uses the 'elastic' transition between images.

This doesn't work on my android phone (Android version 4.0.4) with the stock browser

The "box" pops up but the image is not displayed.

The second example (which uses the 'fade' transition ) works fine on my Android phone.

Is this a problem on other versions of Android?

Does anyone know of a fix for the code so that the "elastic" transition will work on Android?

Comment: As of 23 June 2013 this is no longer a problem. It now works on my Android phone (now version 4.1.2) I assume that an update of colorbox has fixed the problem